# Значение свойства length непустой html-коллекции странным образом меняется в зависимости от способа обращения к нему

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Есть примитивный кодаКусок:

```
    var targets = document.getElementsByClassName('pd-nav-tg');
    console.log(targets);
    console.log('length: ' + targets.length);
    setTimeout(function() { console.log('length: ' + targets.length); }, 0);
```

в документе на самом деле ровно **3** элемента класса 'pd-nav-tg'.

Но вот какое чудо в консоли:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему так происходит?
Знаю, что getElementsByClassName возвращает "живую" коллекцию, но работа с этими элементами никакая не ведется параллельно, а приведенный код выполняется после события DOMContentLoaded.

---

̶Г̶о̶в код целиком (чертовщина происходит в **prepearing()**):

```
class PuduNavigation {
constructor(args) {
    this.activeTargets = new Object();
    this.activeButtons = new Object();

    switch (args['compat']) {
        case 'bootstrap' : this.defaultActiveBtnClassName = 'active'; break;
        default : this.defaultActiveBtnClassName = 'none';
    }

    window.addEventListener('load', this.prepearing());
}

prepearing() {
    var targets = document.getElementsByClassName('pd-nav-tg');
    console.log(targets);
    console.log('length: ' + targets.length);
    setTimeout(function() { console.log('length: ' + targets.length); }, 0);

    for (var target of targets) {
        if (target.classList.contains('pd-nav-default')) {
            if (target.hasAttribute('data-layer')) {
                let layer = target.getAttribute('data-layer');
                this.activeTargets[layer] = target;
            }
            else this.activeTargets['pd-default-layer'] = target;
        }
    }

    for (let layer in this.activeTargets) {
        this.activeTargets[layer].classList.add('pd-nav-tg-active');
    }

    var navs = document.getElementsByClassName('pd-nav-btn');
    for (var nav of navs) {
        if (!nav.hasAttribute('data-target')) 
            throw "One of pd-nav elements has no 'data-target' attribute.";
        let targetName = nav.getAttribute('data-target');
        for (let layer in this.activeTargets) {
            if (this.activeTargets[layer].getAttribute('id') == targetName) {
                this.activeButtons[layer] = nav;
                this.addActiveClass(nav);
            }
        }
        nav.addEventListener('click', function() { 
            //this.switchActiveTarget(this);
            console.log(this);
        });
    }
}

addActiveClass(nav) {
    if (nav.classList.contains('pd-nav-custom') || this.defaultActiveBtnClassName == 'none') {
        let className = nav.classList[0] + '-active';
        nav.classList.add(className);
    }   
    else nav.classList.add(this.defaultActiveBtnClassName);
}

removeActiveClass(nav) {
    if (nav.classList.contains('pd-nav-custom') || this.defaultActiveBtnClassName == 'none') {
        let className = nav.classList[0] + '-active';
        nav.classList.remove(className);
    }   
    else nav.classList.remove(this.defaultActiveBtnClassName);
}

switchActiveTarget(clickedNav) {
    var targetPageName = clickedNav.getAttribute('data-target');
    var targetPage = document.getElementById(targetPageName);
    if (!targetPage) throw "There's no page with id: '" + targetPageName + "'.";
    var layer;
    if (targetPage.hasAttribute('data-layer'))
        layer =  targetPage.getAttribute('data-layer');
    else layer = 'pd-default-layer';

    if (targetPage != this.activeTargets[layer]) {
        this.activeTargets[layer].classList.remove('pd-nav-tg-active');
        targetPage.classList.add('pd-nav-tg-active');
        this.activeTargets[layer] = targetPage;

        this.addActiveClass(clickedNav);
        this.removeActiveClass(this.activeButtons[layer]);
        this.activeButtons[layer] = clickedNav;
    }
}
```

}

А дальше там где-то просиходит создание объекта

```
var noname = new PuduNavigation(args);
```

Comment: Вы уверены, что этот код после `window.addEventListener("load", function(event) {});`? Покажите весь код.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все нормально, так и должно быть. `document.getElementsByClassName` возвращает "живую" коллекцию элементов.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName

Разберем этот код.

```
var targets = document.getElementsByClassName('pd-nav-tg');
```

Ссылка `targets` указывает на такую живую коллекцию, которая отражает текущее состояние документа.

```
console.log(targets);
```

Здесь происходит еще одна неочевидная вещь. Консоль запоминает ссылку на объект и обновляет показываемые значения, отражая текущее состояние объекта.

```
console.log('length: ' + targets.length);
```

Здесь выводится число элементов на момент выполнения этой строчки кода.

```
setTimeout(function() { console.log('length: ' + targets.length); }, 0);
```

Здесь выводится число элементов после окончания загрузки документа.

---

```
window.addEventListener('load', this.prepearing());
```

Это просто неправильно. `this.prepearing()` выполняется в этой строчке (а не после события `DOMContentLoaded`) и ничего не возвращает. Надо:

```
window.addEventListener('load', this.prepearing.bind(this));
```

Comment: Не нормально. Код после `window.addEventListener('load'`. Не должно там 0 быть.

Comment: `window.addEventListener('load', this.prepearing.bind(this));`
- если первый this - это указатель на экземпляр класса PuduNavigation (верно?), то на что указывает второй?

Comment: @AlexeyLyulenkov На то же самое - тот же объект `PuduNavigation`. `bind` возвращает обертку вокруг функции `prepearing`. При вызове этой обертки, `prepearing` выполнится в контексте того объекта, который был передан в `bind`.

Comment: @AlexeyLyulenkov Не совсем так. Если бы Вы использовали `this.prepearing`, то произошла бы "потеря контекста вызова". `this` внутри функции показывал бы на `window`. Но ошибки тогда, вероятно, натолкнули бы Вас на решение.

Comment: @Igor дошло, спасибо! коммент предыдущий удалил по ошибке, вы правы, в любом случае, поторопился